# What effect does voting to Leave Open have?

Tags: support, close-review-queue

In the close votes queue I can do four things

- Leave Open
- Close
- Edit
- Skip

I think I understand quite well what happens if I select `Close`, and I think if I `Skip` or `Edit`, I *believe* I might get presented with the same question when I return to the queue later, if it hasn't already been closed.

If I vote to Leave Open, I think I never encounter the question in the queue again. Am I mistaken about that?

**More importantly**, does voting to Leave Open have any further effect? Does it cancel out a Close Vote? Does it otherwise cause the question in question to be removed from the queue, given enough agreement from other voters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Leave open starts a 3 strikes system. 3 leave open votes will remove the question from the queue.  If you notice lots of close votes on a question you do not think should be closed, it is a very good idea to leave a comment addressing the close voters with your reasoning.
- Close adds another close vote to the question. As usual 5 votes are required to close a question.
- Edit allows you to edit the question and then *removes it from the queue*.
- Skip moves you to the next question in the queue.

With the exception of skip you will never be shown a question again if you use an action with it.

Comment: @Zanna Yes, close votes begin to "age" away 14 days after the first vote was cast. If the question has received >=100 views they begin to age 4 days after the last vote was cast.  This happens at a rate of 1 per day once the aging has begun. see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/203389

Comment: I deleted my comment because jokerdino pointed me to the help centre page that explains this (oops! should have read before asking) but thank you very much for the additional detail & link :)

Comment: Will `Edit` remove the question from a reviewers queue or from the queue of all reviewers?

Comment: @Anwar there is only 1 queue that all reviewers go through. So yes, it removes it for all reviewers.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for clearing this